# Sort a list of tuples by descending percentage with hierarchical order

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm trying to sort an ingredient statement with multiple levels in order of dominance (descending by percentage).

I'm using Python and I have a list of tuples, each tuple has the following variables: (ingredient, percentage, childID, parentID).

It comes from data that looks sort of like this, the data can be entered in any order. The columns below are Ingredients/Subingredients, percentages, childID, parentID.

```
#Ing1   30%             1   0
#---Sub1    30%         2   1
#---Sub2    60%         3   1
#------Sub3     15%     4   3
#------Sub4     85%     5   3
#---Sub5    10%         6   1
#Ing2   10%             7   0
#Ing3   60%             5   0
```

My existing code outputs this to me in a list that like this (the order it's entered):

```
list = [(Ing1,30,1,0),(Sub1,30,2,1),(Sub2,60,3,1),(Sub3,15,4,3),(Sub4,85,5,3),(Sub5,10,6,1),(Ing2,10,7,0),(Ing3,60,5,0)]
```

What I need to do is sort this list descending buy percentage while keeping the hierarchy intact from the lower levels up.  So the level 3 ingredients (Sub3, Sub4) first, then the next level up, then the top level.
The sub levels need to sort with their parent.

So, for the example above, I need output to be in this order:

```
> #Ing3 60%             5   0
> #Ing1 30%             1   0
> #---Sub2  60%         3   1
> #------Sub4   85%     5   3
> #------Sub3   15%     4   3
> #---Sub1  30%         2   1
> #---Sub5  10%         6   1
> #Ing2 10%             7   0
```

So the list should look like this:

```
list = [(Ing3,60,5,0),(Ing1,30,1,0),(Sub2,60,3,1),(Sub4,85,5,3),(Sub3,15,4,3),(Sub1,30,2,1),(Sub5,10,6,1),(Ing2,10,7,0)]
```

What's the most elegant way to do this in Python.  Oh and another caveat as I'm limited as to what modules I can import.  If it's not an included module I probably don't have access to it due to my environment.

Comment: Why is `Sub4`, which contains the greatest buy percentage, listed fourth? Could you please elaborate on how the products are sorted?

Comment: I've got something I'm working on for this, but first I'd like to point out that you shouldn't use "list" as a variable name, because that shadows the "list" builtin.

Comment: Sub4 is essentially a percentage of a percentage because its a subingredient of its parent.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on list. Only used list for this example.  The actual variable I use is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a generator like this:

```
lst = [('Ing1',30,1,0),
       ('Sub1',30,2,1),
       ('Sub2',60,3,1),
       ('Sub3',15,4,3),
       ('Sub4',85,5,3),
       ('Sub5',10,6,1),
       ('Ing2',10,7,0),
       ('Ing3',60,5,0)]

def sort_hierarchical(lst, parent=0):
    # sort the current layer (excluding all other elements) by the second element
    res = sorted([i for i in lst if i[3] == parent], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    for item in res:
        yield item
        # recurse for all childs of this item
        for subitem in sort_hierarchical(lst, parent=item[2]):
            yield subitem

>>> list(sort_hierarchical(lst))
[('Ing3', 60, 5, 0),
 ('Ing1', 30, 1, 0),
 ('Sub2', 60, 3, 1),
 ('Sub4', 85, 5, 3),
 ('Sub3', 15, 4, 3),
 ('Sub1', 30, 2, 1),
 ('Sub5', 10, 6, 1),
 ('Ing2', 10, 7, 0)]
```

It could be even simplified further if you sort the list just once before you pass it to the function. Then you only have to filter the items not sort them multiple times:

```
def return_hierarchical(lst, parent=0):
    for item in (i for i in lst if i[3] == parent):
        yield item
        for subitem in return_hierarchical(lst, parent=item[2]):
            yield subitem

>>> list(return_hierarchical(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)))
[('Ing3', 60, 5, 0),
 ('Ing1', 30, 1, 0),
 ('Sub2', 60, 3, 1),
 ('Sub4', 85, 5, 3),
 ('Sub3', 15, 4, 3),
 ('Sub1', 30, 2, 1),
 ('Sub5', 10, 6, 1),
 ('Ing2', 10, 7, 0)]
```

In Python-3.3+ you can use [`yield from`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) and make it even shorter:

```
def return_hierarchical(lst, parent=0):
    for item in (i for i in lst if i[3] == parent):
        yield item
        yield from return_hierarchical(lst, parent=item[2])
```

### General notes:

I renamed your `list` to `lst` so it doesn't shadow the built-in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#func-list).

You're dealing with tuples but you refer to them by names so you could also use [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). This allows you to refer to the items by attribute as well:

```
from collections import namedtuple

ingredient = namedtuple('Ingredient', ['ingredient', 'percentage', 'order', 'parent'])

lst = [ingredient('Ing1',30,1,0), ingredient('Sub1',30,2,1), ingredient('Sub2',60,3,1),
       ingredient('Sub3',15,4,3), ingredient('Sub4',85,5,3), ingredient('Sub5',10,6,1),
       ingredient('Ing2',10,7,0), ingredient('Ing3',60,5,0)]

def return_hierarchical(lst, parent=0):
    for item in (i for i in lst if i.parent == parent):
        yield item
        yield from return_hierarchical(lst, parent=item.parent)

list(sort_hierarchical(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x.percentage, reverse=True)))
```

Personally I like `namedtuple`s but some don't and you said you're limited by your imports (it's in the standard library but nevertheless) so I only included it here ... at the end.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this! This looks like what I'm looking for! Will you know if I run into trouble. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @drun2969 No problem. I don't know if you will run into trouble (at least code-wise I doubt it - except you have circular parents). Please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/317868) the most helpful answer. :)

Comment: Thanks, I will. I meant to say "I will LET you know if I run into trouble." I wont have time to try until later, but one think that may trip me up is that there is no limit to the levels in the actual system. So I can't assume there are only 3 as in my example.

Comment: @drun2969 Ah okay :) It should work fine unless you run into the recursion limit of python (it's roughly 300 but can be changed).

Comment: It worked! I had to troubleshoot an issue but it had to due with the way I was creating the list.  I was able to use your code exactly as written above!  THANKS! you saved me hours of banging my head against the wall.  I will now read more about Generators so I can figure out WHY it worked.